# Trying to stop loading same component again and again

Tags: vue.js

## About the code

Using Laravel 5.8 and Vue.js components.

## Issue Details

There are 3 tabs. When I click component 1, it loads. Then I click Component 2, It loads. So far everything is okay.

When I go back to Component 1, it loads the component again. Here the problem is that there is captcha which gets the response code again from server because the component is loading everytime on clicking the tab.

Can i stop loading the component loading after first time? I meant, I just want to reuse the html which was loaded.

**Main Component**

```
<template>    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <b-tabs pills card vertical>
            <b-tab title="Main" active>
                <profile></profile>
            </b-tab>
            <b-tab title="Comp 1" @click="setComponent('comp1')">
                <component :is = "comp1"></component>
            </b-tab>
            <b-tab title="Comp 2" @click="setComponent('comp2')">
                <component :is = "comp2"></component>
            </b-tab>
        </b-tabs>
    </div>
</template>

<script>        
    export default {
        methods: {
            setComponent(name) {
                if(name == "comp1") {
                    this.comp1 = name;
                }
                else {
                    this.comp2 = name;
                }
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {   
                comp1: '', comp2: ''
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Component - Comp 1**

```
<template>    
    <div class="container">
        Comp 1 rendered
        <vue-recaptcha  
            :sitekey="My Site Key"> 
        </vue-recaptcha> 
    </div>
</template>
```

**Component - Comp 2**

```
<template>    
    <div class="container">
        Comp 2 Rendered
        <vue-recaptcha  
            :sitekey="My Site Key"> 
        </vue-recaptcha> 
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: [keep-alive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components).

Comment: Have you tried to keep those two components between keep-alive? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Answer (score 0):

You can adds `keep-alive`, getting the components are not destroyed re-create

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <keep-alive>
        <b-tabs pills card vertical>
            <b-tab title="Main" active>
                <profile></profile>
            </b-tab>
            <b-tab title="Comp 1" @click="setComponent('comp1')">
                <component :is = "comp1"></component>
            </b-tab>
            <b-tab title="Comp 2" @click="setComponent('comp2')">
                <component :is = "comp2"></component>
            </b-tab>
        </b-tabs>
    </keep-alive>
</div>
```

After that you will have two new hooks in both child components, *activated* and *deactivated*.